# why wouldn't it work? using getMouseClicked with no results

Tags: java, swing

this program suppose to create a window that has a status bar under it that shows how many times the mouse was clicked without being moved on the screen. when you move the mouse and click it suppose to start a new count. it also distinguishes different mouse buttons. I've followed this code exactly as a tutorial I saw, but it doesn't work. I just get the window with a status bar that never changes.

```
public class Adapter_class extends JFrame {

    private String details;
    private JLabel statusBar;
    public Adapter_class() {

        super("Adapter mouse:");

        this.statusBar = new JLabel("Default");
        add(this.statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        addMouseListener(new MouseClass());
    }

    private class MouseClass extends MouseAdapter {
        public void MouseClicked (MouseEvent event) {
            details = String.format("You clicked the mouse %d", event.getClickCount());


            //this is for using a mouse from a mac
            if (event.isMetaDown())
            details += " with the right mouse button";
            else if (event.isAltDown())
            details += " with the center mouse button";
            else
            details += " with the left mouse button";

            statusBar.setText(details);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Adapter_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Adapter_class window = new Adapter_class();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(400, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public abstract class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
```

Use this:

```
private class MouseClass extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event){
```

Here the function you have to write is  `**mouseClicked**` not `**MouseClicked**`

Thats why it helps to use annotations.
@Override would have helped you immediately.

Answer (score 5):

You have written the method `MouseClicked` with capital M. Use the lower case version

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { ... }
```

Otherwise you are creating a new method and not override the adapter's one. You may also want to include a `@Override` annotation which would force the compiler to show you the issue.